# Why do I get the error fromFile not a built-in function in botframework

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, adaptive-dialogs

I have upgraded to the latest version of botframework and started to get the error:

> 

Oops, it looks like something went wrong. Error:[Error] D:\home\site\wwwroot\Dialogs\RootDialog\LG\en\RootDialog_en.lg line 15:2 - line 15:69: Error occurred when parsing expression ‘json(fromFile(’…/…/Cards/en/OnChooseIntentAdaptiveCard.json’))'. fromFile does not have an evaluator, it’s not a built-in function or a custom function.

> 

LG code:

```
# AdaptiveCard
[Activity
    Attachments = ${json(AdaptiveCard.Definition())}
]



# AdaptiveCard.Definition
- ${json(fromFile('../../Cards/en/OnChooseIntentAdaptiveCard.json'))}



# chooseIntentResponseWithCard_en()
[Activity
    Attachments = ${ActivityAttachment(json(fromFile('../../Cards/en/OnChooseIntentAdaptiveCard.json')), 'adaptiveCard')}
]



# Greeting_en()
[Activity
    Attachments = ${ActivityAttachment(json(fromFile('../../Cards/en/GreetingCard.json')), 'adaptiveCard')}
    AttachmentLayout = list
]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromFile` is [now disabled by default](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/5953/files). You can change set the value on the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration.Templates class:

`Templates.EnableFromFile = true;`

Comment: Is there a changelog for botframework versions or something similar where we can follow the changes?

Comment: You can keep an eye [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/releases). You can also look at the branch commits (main or whatever version you are interested in): https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/commits/4.15